# How to find the value of $\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\log x}\,dx$?

Tags: integration

I want to find the value of
 $$\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\log x}\,dx$$
where $\log x$ stands for the natrual logarithm.

I put it in the wolfram alpha, and it saids it's $\log 2$.
(Refer to : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+%28x-1%29%2F%28lnx%29)

But I can't figure out how it comes to that value.
Help me to find out the procedure from that integration to get $\log 2$.

Comment: And sorry for the inconvenience of ill-written formula, could you tell me where the syntax for Mathjax is wrong?

Comment: You need to clarify the question. It is not at all clear what the formula is meant to be... Did you mean $\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\ln x} dx$? To see how I wrote the latter, right click over the formula and select 'Show Math as' and select 'Tex Commands'.

Comment: Thanks to @copper.hat, that's what I wanted to ask for.

Comment: But in your link the function is $x-1/\ln(x)$. You first have to learn the basics of writing a fraction of functions before asking questions.

Comment: @copper.hat I see there $\int (x-1/\ln(x))dx$ and not  $\int ((x-1)/\ln(x))dx$ as asked.

Comment: @copper.hat just did it, the same.

Comment: @Karl: Dunno what to say, it looks fine to me when I click through...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a method using the Feynman integration trick:
Consider
$$I(a)=\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^a-1}{\log x}\,dx$$

Then we have 
$$I'(a)=\frac{d}{da}\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^a-1}{\log x}\,dx=\int\limits_0^1 \frac{d}{da}\left[\frac{x^a-1}{\log x}\right]\,dx=\int\limits_0^1 x^a\,dx=\frac{1}{a+1}$$

Now integrating with respect to $a$ gives 
$$I(a)=\log(a+1)+C$$

Now, to find $C$, we can note that the $I(0)=0$ (because when $a=0$ the numerator turns into $1-1=0$). Hence $0=\log(0+1)+C$, so $C=0$.

Hence we have $I(a)=\log(a+1)$, and in particular we care about the $a=1$ case in which the solution is just $\log(2)$.

Comment: You should have looked for duplicates

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter! And it's my fault for not noticing there's already similar question exist.

Comment: FYI, I didn't down-voted.

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ So, as you have shown, my answer is close enough to certainly be a repeat, but I am not convinced that this $\textit{specific}$ question is a duplicate - in the case of $\frac{x-1}{\ln{x}}$ there may be some nice symmetry argument

Comment: @MathysistK You're very welcome - this type of integration trick is a lot of fun

Comment: In current situation, This question and answer adds nothing to the site.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt I've pointed out exact duplicate.

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ thanks for finding it! I agree - nothing new here so far at least.