# Integrating functions

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $f(x)$ from 0 to 1 where $f(x) = \frac{x^3-1}{lnx}$

I received this problem and a variety of others in an advanced mathematics exam. I tried a classical trigonometric substituition approach with $x=sec^\frac{2}{3}t$ but it gets really long and still gives no answer. I tried multiplying the numerator and denominator by $x$ and trying $ln(lnx)=z$ substitution as $dz=\frac{1}{lnx.x}dx$.
I am not able to see which definite integral properties would actually help me here, either. Please advise.

Comment: $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^3 - 1}{\ln x}\,dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^{3} e^{y\ln x}\,dy\,dx = \int_0^3 \int_0^1 x^y\,dx\,dy = \int_0^3 \frac{1}{1+y}\,dy$$

Comment: @r9m. Nice solution, indeed ! I was, just being stupid, thinking about the antiderivative.

Comment: See also here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082626/how-to-find-the-value-of-int-01-fracx-1-log-x-dx/1082642#1082642

Comment: Ohh right. The parameter trick. Damn. Thanks for reminding me!